# Getting seg fault when using malloc with double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm using something like this to allocate memory with a function (in C)

```
void myfunction(struct mystruct** ss) {
    // some code
    *ss = malloc( 1024 * sizeof (struct mystruct) );
    // some code
}    
int main()
{
   struct mystruct **x;
   *x = NULL;
   myfunction(x);
   return 0;
}
```

but I'm getting seg fault. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4):

After `struct mystruct **x;`, the variable `x` is uninitialized. It is illegal to read from it as your program does in `*x = NULL;`.

You may have wanted to write:

```
int main()
{
   struct mystruct *x;
   x = NULL;
   myfunction(&x);
   return 0;
}
```

But it is impossible to be sure, as your program does not do anything meaningful.
Note that `x = NULL;` is unnecessary anyway: `x` will be initialized inside `myfunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

you never make any storage for the underlying pointer, there is storage for the `**` and the object but not the `*`...

```
struct mystruct **x,*y;
x = &y;
myfunction(x);
return 0;
```